# Upload content without coding again

Tags: html, rss

Hello guys I have this website project that the customer wants to upload images-videos-text
without writing -or- changing codes at all.The only things he wants is to upload via a panel directly to his website. I thought of rss but i am not really sure about that.

What can I do?

Comment: Use a CMS like WordPress or create your own.

Comment: What language are you using (php,java,.net or  just static html)?

Comment: Just static HTML. Basically all i need is a CMS without using joomla or wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered installing a content management system? Whether you use something similar to Joomla or Wordpress might be a bit invasive, but you may consider DreamWeaver/Contribute...

Good luck!

Comment: How is DreamWeaver a CMS?

Comment: No I am writing code from scratch,so I don't use Wordpress or Joomla.
By the way can you suggest me a content management system?

Comment: @StratosAsimis WordPress and Joomla are content management systems (CMS).

Comment: Oh! Didn't knew that!So, How can I do this without them?

Comment: Dreamweaver is the platform that you would use to create the original content, structure, some of the light scripting and templates. Contribute is then used by the user as a CMS and the user can then upload/add/edit/delete content in the areas that you designate. This sounds like the best solution for the situation that you are describing. It will have the easiest set up for you and the shortest learning curve for your client. Win/Win solution! Best of luck!

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara Dreamweaver is not a CMS/ Dreamweaver coupled with Contribute is. The original website is created within DW and then once completed the client will use contribute as a content management system. This is the most comprehensive CMS out there. Joomla, Wordpress, DotNetNuke, SharePoint, etc... are extremely limiting from a web dev standpoint. Basically, although you can change the source code, you are limited to the confines of the app. [br] With DreamWeaver/Contribute you control the entire site from creation. Not to mention, you have greater flexibility on the client end.

Comment: @StratosAsimis if you design your site with DW then you can issue Contribute to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla! is one of the better CMS (and maybe THE better cms). It give possibility to upload and publish any kind of content without coding.

Comment: Without Joomla? The website is ready,the only thing i want is the customer to upload content without coding, from another page. for example: www.ex@mple.com/admin

Answer (score 0):

You could just configure a WYSIWYG for your site (i recommend [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/))